# Is it possible to play team deathmatch or clan arena with more than two teams?

Tags: quake-live

In Quake Live, Team Deathmatch and Clan Arena are played between two teams. Is it possible to change this? There are some mods in Quake 3 where more than two teams was possible (e.g. [Tribal CTF](https://www.fileplanet.com/archive/p-76293/Q3-Tribal-CTF-Beta) mod for CTF and [TheTeamMod](https://www.quake3world.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=50129) for TDM). The nature of Quake Live though seems not to allow this option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Quake Live allows more than two teams to participate in those two gamemodes.

I did some research on the modding communities built around Quake Live and have not come up with any results pertaining to allowing a higher quantity of participating teams.

Good luck in case you find extra information regarding it. If I've made a mistake with the information I've provided, please let me know and I'll fix it or remove it.